# Data Explorer forgotten me - new account?

Tags: support, bug, data-explorer

> **NOTE:** My account seems to be linking back to the original. I guess that makes this issue closed?

I had many (hundreds?) of queries in Data Explorer, and with the new google log in, they are all gone? When I log in with my google account, which I have always done, I now have a new user created?

[image]

I understand that the google signin has changed, but, if it cannot be fixed, can all the old queries I have built be merged in with the new account? [Apparent new account](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/18331/) <-> ["My" account I want to keep](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/12469/rolfl)

Comment: Not a [dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254115/server-error-in-application-on-sede-with-new-auth) but either Nick or Tim has to fix this I think

Comment: Does this mean that I should wait a bit with logging in on SEDE so that the same thing doesn't happen to me?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg for me it worked without any issue. I'm not sure which exact state (being logged-in/logged-out, session still hanging around) causes this problem of not linking to your old profile. If you want to be sure this doesn't happen for you, I would wait until Nick has confirmed the root cause.