# Data Explorer OpenID issues

Tags: support, data-explorer, user-accounts, openid, stack-exchange-openid

When you login to data.stackexchange.com through something like Google, you get a nice jon.doe account. However, I have changed my username to UniKitty. ([Here's the account](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/18160/unikitty)). However, I logout and login to my Stack Exchange OpenID. Now it makes a [new account](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/18794/unikitty18795) with a messed-up username. It has "unikitty", but with the numbers behind. This should be fixed.

<sub>Feel free to merge the accounts</sub>

Comment: maybe related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254343/data-explorer-forgotten-me-new-account

Comment: Then this question exists to get me a merge

Comment: Merging more or less doesn't exist on SEDE. It can be kind of faked, but it's usually not worth manually editing OpenIDs for that. Enjoy your two accounts?

Comment: Plus, you signed in with two different credentials and the data explorer created an account for each one. That seems... logical. I don't think this is a bug. Tim Stone can confirm one way or the other, but I retagged to [support] on the meantime.

Comment: @AnnaLear Well both logins can be used to login to Unikitty on any SE site like meta.SE. So it should detect that and log me in as unikitty there as well  for both logins

Comment: @UniKitty Not necessarily. The Data Explorer is a completely separate system. It doesn't know about about SE network accounts.

Comment: @AnnaLear But it can authenticate with the SE systems! For example the "login with stackexchange" option

Comment: @UniKitty That simply means "log in using Stack Exchange OpenID". It's no different than using Google, Wordpress, or any other provider as far as the data explorer is concerned.