# Data Explorer created a new account; issuing an account merge request resulted in a server error

Tags: support, data-explorer, 500-server-error

I tried to log onto the Data Explorer through my normal OpenID (Google), but I got a brand new account instead. My real account is [4216](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/4216/chrisaycock). Is there some way to ensure that my OpenID goes to that one, and not the newer [18473](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/18473/christopher-aycock)?

---

I filed the above via the [Contact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) page, but that resulted in

> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred
> while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded
> and we have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
>
> It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional
> information about this error, do so at our feedback site,
> http://meta.stackexchange.com.

So I'm filing two bug reports here.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254115/server-error-in-application-on-sede-with-new-auth and also related with this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254343/data-explorer-forgotten-me-new-account  I'm explicitly do not close vote this as a duplicate because I think all are similar but distinct cases.

Comment: I'll see if I can figure out why the login transition got borked for some people. The merge option on Contact will definitely **not** work, though, since Data Explorer is completely separate. It should probably complain about not knowing what that site is instead of erroring out, though.

Comment: @TimStone Any luck with this? OpenID still logs me into the wrong account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote Community Support directly and got this answer:

> We generally do not perform merges on Data Explorer. That is a very different system and requires bugging developers in order to get anything done over there because no one on the support team has access to it. Keep in mind that Data Explorer has no concept of a "network account" where you can add as many credentials as you'd like. If you use a different credential at any point, it will create a separate account for each credential, and they cannot be attached together. We recommend just using whatever account you can access to do any tasks you need to do and not worrying about what account it's connected to.

In my digging around, I accidentally created [yet another account](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/28700/christopher-c-aycock). I'm going to let sleeping dogs lie.

Comment: It's not that it matters a lot, it's just that I didn't expect stackexchange to have a bug like this going on for a long time. It happened to me today.