# Data explorer site created new jon.doe account, instead of logging me to the old one

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, data-explorer, merge-accounts

I've logged in to [data explorer site](https://data.stackexchange.com/), but it didn't recognise my [old account](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/11939/kenorb) and created a [new one](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/22873/jon-doe22874).

Is it possible to merge those accounts, as I can't logging to my old account anymore.

---

Related:

- [How do I get into my data.stackexchange.com account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306567/191655)
- [Two SEDE accounts; please fix and how do I avoid this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261181/191655)

Comment: Similar cases reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256399/data-explorer-created-a-new-account-issuing-an-account-merge-request-resulted-i). This is not a duplicate btw, I did recall this issue was fixed but apparently it isn't.

Comment: Your accounts have been merged now.

Comment: @rene I don't think it can be fixed, SE employee has to manually merge the accounts each time. So far it's rare enough to not make it a big deal probably.

Comment: @ShadowWizard according to Tim he has a patch ready that needs to be pulled and deployed ...

Comment: @rene you mean the pull request mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264145/152859)? It can take years until Nick will deploy it on the server. (I decided to stop nagging him  long ago, it's pointless.)

Comment: yes, that is the one @ShadowWizard I think Nick fancies breaking Stack Overflow more then doing a pull on SEDE ;)

Comment: @Oded can you review and deploy SEDE pull requests, or is it something that only Nick is doing?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - technically, I can...

Comment: @Oded I can see the "but...". Thanks anyway, and happy bug hunting! :)

Comment: Another related bug: [How do I get into my data.stackexchange.com account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306567/191655).

Comment: @Oded Can you merge my two accounts, too: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331101/in-data-stackexchange-a-login-action-for-an-existing-account-created-a-new-user