# How do I get into my data.stackexchange.com account?

Tags: support, data-explorer, login, user-accounts

When I log into https://data.stackexchange.com/ with either open id or google or stack exchange, it takes me to some fake username **jon-doe27508**

[image: john doe ?!]

That's not me: https://data.stackexchange.com/users/27507/jon-doe27508

This is me: https://data.stackexchange.com/users/7549/wim

I've tried logging out of jon-doe and re-logging in with the other various options available and it seems to always go back to jon doe.  I have saved queries in my real profile, how can I log in as me?

Comment: this is related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261181/158100 but that pull request from Tim is still not merged. Needs a dev to fiddle with the db.

Comment: The PR is 2 and a half years old and has a billion conflicts now.  Is there any quick fix avail?

Comment: If bribing Nick Craver is acceptable in a quick fix scenario. If you have twitter, stalk him there.

Comment: I don't care if I can't merge accounts.  Just want to be able to login again.

Comment: Sure, still needs Nick, he knows and has access to SEDE

Comment: Thanks rene.  So this bug has been around for years now ... ??

Comment: Yeah, it pops-up now and then. I already left a message in chat in the hope another SE Dev will pick it up but it might be that Nick owns that feature so he is the person to attend to this issue.

Comment: Related: [Data explorer site created new jon.doe account, instead of logging me to the old one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277611/191655).

Comment: I merged the two users, trying to preserve the new account and its credentials, but... I'm not 100% sure that worked as I thought it would. Looks like the old openid (in a format that Google retired a long time ago) is still displayed on the resulting profile. I don't have the code/DBs in front of me right now to look deeper into it, though. Try logging in again just in case? If it doesn't work, I can fix it up more reliably tomorrow.

Comment: It looks like whatever you did worked.  Thanks!